# VBA loop copy and paste rows based one a specific cells value

Tags: excel, vba

I'm very new to coding VBA and am trying to create a way for excel to see a value in a specific cell on one sheet, then copy a range of rows on another and pasting them below. I have written this but I will need to go up to at least 50 copies and am aware that the code will get too long to run. Is there an easier way to do this? Or a way to condense the code so it all runs on one sub?

```
'1 copy
 Worksheets("Sheet 1").Activate
 If Range("D23") = ("2") Then
 Worksheets("Sheet 2").Activate
 Worksheets("Sheet 2").Range("14:24").Copy Range("26:36")
 End If
'2 copies
 Worksheets("Sheet 1").Activate
 If Range("D23") = ("3") Then
 Worksheets("Sheet 2").Activate
 Worksheets("Sheet 2").Range("14:24").Copy Range("26:36")
 Worksheets("Sheet 2").Range("14:24").Copy Range("38:48")
 End If
'3 copies
 Worksheets("Sheet 1").Activate
 If Range("D23") = ("4") Then
 Worksheets("Sheet 2").Activate
 Worksheets("Sheet 2").Range("14:24").Copy Range("26:36")
 Worksheets("Sheet 2").Range("14:24").Copy Range("38:48")
 Worksheets("Sheet 2").Range("14:24").Copy Range("50:60")
 End If
```

Answer (score 0):

and welcome to VBA, first you don't need to Activate every time you're copying.

```
If Range("D23") = ("2") Then
Worksheets("Sheet 2").Range("14:24").Copy Range("26:36")
End If
```

Also to avoid multiple lines I imagine something like this:

```
For count= 1 To 50

If Range("D" & count) = ("2") Then
    Worksheets("Sheet 2").Range("14:24").Copy Range("26:36")
End If
If Range("D" & count) = ("3") Then
    Worksheets("Sheet 2").Range("14:24").Copy Range("26:36")
    Worksheets("Sheet 2").Range("14:24").Copy Range("38:48")
End If
If Range("D" & count) = ("4") Then
    Worksheets("Sheet 2").Range("14:24").Copy Range("26:36")
    Worksheets("Sheet 2").Range("14:24").Copy Range("38:48")
    Worksheets("Sheet 2").Range("14:24").Copy Range("50:60")
End If

Next count
```

That code goes from D1 to D50 copying, just need to adapt the Copy Range dynamically.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the sheets! But sadly when I try to run the code I get Run time error 13: type mismatch on the "If Range("D" & Count) = ("2") Then". Sadly my knowledge on VBA is lacking and I don't know how to go about fixing this problem, any thoughts?

Comment: I validated it and it does compile, the error is not around there.. I'm not getting a run time error.